# Getting error as NOReverseMatch in django?

Tags: python, django

[image]I am a newbie in django learning django with a online course by creating a realestate project.In this project I am having listings app which shows some of the listings in the web page from the database But I am getting an error of Reverse for 'listing' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['listings/listings/$']
My listings urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
      url(r'^$', views.index, name='listings'),
      url(r'^listings/<int:listing_id>$', views.listing, name='listing'),
      url('search', views.search,name='search')
]
```

My listings views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator

from .models import Listing

def index(request):
  listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)

  paginator = Paginator(listings, 6)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)

  context = {
    'listings': paged_listings
  }

  return render(request, 'listings/listings.html', context)

def listing(request, listing_id):
  listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)

  context = {
    'listing': listing
  }

  return render(request, 'listings/listing.html', context)

def search(request):
  queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date')

  # Keywords
  if 'keywords' in request.GET:
    keywords = request.GET['keywords']
    if keywords:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

  # City
  if 'city' in request.GET:
    city = request.GET['city']
    if city:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)

  # State
  if 'state' in request.GET:
    state = request.GET['state']
    if state:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(state__iexact=state)

  # Bedrooms
  if 'bedrooms' in request.GET:
    bedrooms = request.GET['bedrooms']
    if bedrooms:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bedrooms__lte=bedrooms)

  # Price
  if 'price' in request.GET:
    price = request.GET['price']
    if price:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(price__lte=price)

  context = {
    'state_choices': state_choices,
    'bedroom_choices': bedroom_choices,
    'price_choices': price_choices,
    'listings': queryset_list,
    'values': request.GET
  }

  return render(request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

My listings template

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% load humanize %}

{% block title %} | Browse Property Listings {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section id="showcase-inner" class="py-5 text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="display-4">Browse Our Properties</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, pariatur!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Breadcrumb -->
  <section id="bc" class="mt-3">
    <div class="container">
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}">
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Browse Listings</li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Listings -->
  <section id="listings" class="py-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        {% if listings %}
          {% for listing in listings %}
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
              <div class="card listing-preview">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}" alt="">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h2>
                    <span class="badge badge-secondary text-white">${{ listing.price | intcomma }}</span>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                    <h4 class="text-primary">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
                    <p>
                      <i class="fas fa-map-marker text-secondary"></i> {{ listing.city }} {{ listing.state }}, {{ listing.zipcode }}</p>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Sqft: {{ listing.sqft }}</div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <i class="fas fa-car"></i> Garage: {{ listing.garage }}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Bedrooms: {{ listing.bedrooms }}</div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <i class="fas fa-bath"></i> Bathrooms: {{ listing.bathrooms }}</div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <i class="fas fa-user"></i> {{ listing.realtor }}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row text-secondary pb-2">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ listing.list_date | timesince }}</div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <a href="{% url 'listing' listing_id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>No Listings Available</p>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {% if listings.has_other_pages %}
            <ul class="pagination">
              {% if listings.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a href="?page={{listings.previous_page_number}}" class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                  <a class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
              {% for i in listings.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if listings.number == i %}
                  <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
                  </li>
                {% else %}
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a href="?page={{i}}" class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% if listings.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a href="?page={{listings.next_page_number}}" class="page-link">&raquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                  <a class="page-link">&raquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have to pass a listing_id here. href="{% url 'listing' listing_id=<llisting_id> %}". replace <llisting_id> with id. In your case listing_id = listing.id

Comment: try to change your urls.py url(r'^listings/(?P<listing_id>\d+)/$', views.listing, name='listing')

Comment: change `{% url 'listing' listing_id %}` to `{% url 'listing' listing.id %}`.

Comment: @sandeep as you said I had changed the code and getting error as Could not parse the remainder: '<listing_id>' from '<listing_id>'

Comment: @sandeep in your case I think is fine too, because there is only one get params in url, it's id, and it's not require to specifi it, django will get it automatically, because it's django :)

Comment: you have to use id in place of <listing_id>. In your case listing.id. try listing_id=listing.id

Comment: @ Bakhtiyar as you said I had changed and it is getting syntax error at the next line search url why?

Comment: @ Sandeep even i kept listing.id also getting same error

Comment: Can you show error log? href="{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.id %}" or  href="{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.pk %}" should work.

Comment: If I kept href="{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.pk %}" I am getting the error @ sandeep please see it i had included it now

Comment: @madhavi which django version you are using

Comment: do you have another urls.py in project directory? urls showing listing/listing/1.

Comment: @ sandeep no only one in listings app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using django 3, and url patterns from django 1. Try this:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
      path('', views.index, name='listings'),
      path('listings/<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
      path('search', views.search, name='search')
]
```

in **template**

```
<a href="{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
```

Comment: But I had got doubt my project containing apps some are done with django 1.11 and after that some are done in 3.0 after upgrading from 1.11 to 3.0 all the apps wont change?

Comment: @madhavi I am not sure. You might get some issues. depends on changes from v1 to v2 and v2 to v3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Django version 2+, you could use `path` instead:

```
path('listings/<int:listing_id>/', views.listing, name='listing'),
```

If your using lower django version than 2

```
 url(r'^listings/(?P<listing_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.listing, name='listing'),
```

Now in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'listing' listing.pk %}">
```

Comment: @madhavi did you try the answer ?

Comment: Yes I got the answer actually my django version has been updated your answer worked

Comment: But I had got doubt my project containing apps some are done with django 1.11 and after that some are done in 3.0 after upgrading from 1.11 to 3.0 all the apps wont change?